# installing ruby 1.9.3 in BT5R3 using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

i installed RVM and ran the command

```
rvm requirements
```

and i got the following error;and it kept on coming.

```
root@bt:~# rvm requirements

Checking requirements for ubuntu.

Installing requirements for ubuntu.

Updating system.
Installing required packages: libreadline6-dev, libyaml-dev, libgdbm-dev, 

libffi-dev..

Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev libgdbm-             dev 

libffi-dev',

showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1408964396/package_install_libreadli
ne6-dev_libyaml-dev_libgdbm-dev_libffi-dev.log

current path: /root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/et
c/alternatives/gem-bin:/etc/alternatives/gem-bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin

command(5): requirements_debian_libs_install libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev libgdb
m-dev libffi-dev

+ __rvm_try_sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends --yes install libreadline6-dev
libyaml-dev libgdbm-dev libffi-dev

+ typeset -a command_to_run

+ typeset sudo_path sbin_path missing_paths

+ command_to_run=("$@")

+ ((  UID == 0  ))

+ apt-get --no-install-recommends --yes install libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev lib
gdbm-dev libffi-dev

Reading package lists...

Building dependency tree...

Reading state information...

E: Couldn't find package libreadline6-dev

+ return 100
+ return 100

Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Please help,cannot seem to fix this error.

Thanks

Comment: Which verison of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: im using BackTrack 5r3

Comment: Error is right there: "Couldn't find package libreadline6-dev". BTW you should ask this question on SuperUser or other SE forum.